# Switch open applications between monitors?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a quick keyboard shortcut to switch an application from one monitor to the next when using a 2-monitor setup?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you say switch I'm assuming that you mean move the actual window from one screen to the next.  This is done by either <kbd>win</kbd>**+**<kbd>shift</kbd>**+**<kbd>←</kbd> (or <kbd>→</kbd>) .  If you simply have two apps running and want to switch between the two then the use of either <kbd>alt</kbd>**+**<kbd>tab</kbd> or <kbd>win</kbd>**+**<kbd>tab</kbd> will quickly switch between apps.  (the <kbd>win</kbd>**+**<kbd>tab</kbd> looks cooler).

Comment: Thanks!  That's exactly what I wanted, and the Win+Tab looks like it might be useful also.

Comment: In my case, Win+Shift+Left or Righ Arrow makes the application as large as both monitors instead of switching it from one to another monitor.

Answer (score 0):

[Display Fusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/) will give you that ability, and many many more options for multiple desktops.

Comment: Display Fusion is great and I have the software myself, but since he has win-7 there are already built in keyboard shortcuts for it.