# switch opened windows between two or more monitors?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, multiple-monitors, alt-tab

Is there a shortcut to switch opened windows between two or more monitors? (i.e. Win 1 opened on Monitor 1 is now switched w/ Win 2 opened on Monitor 2 and vice-versa).

I know:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>: But does not switch the applications between monitors.

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[image: WIndows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>: But only moves one window over to the next monitor, and not the other window that is opened.

There was another similar question asked here -- [Switch open applications between monitors?](https://superuser.com/questions/202422/switch-open-applications-between-monitors) -- but it did not provide the answer I was looking for.

Comment: so you are asking for a command that moves ALL opened windows to the other monitor?

Comment: Leon - Switch just the topmost/last-focus on each monitor to the other?  Or swap everything on monitor 1 with everything on 2?  Or ...?  Question isn't clear to some of us ( @FrankThomas ).  Perhaps not relevant but have you thought about virtual desktops?