# Swap open windows on two monitors

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-explorer

I am using two main programs on both of my monitors (one program each), but sometimes I want to see the program on the second monitor on my 'main' monitor.

Can I somehow switch every open window from monitor 1 to 2 and vice versa?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/655442/switch-opened-windows-between-two-or-more-monitors

Answer (score 0):

If you have just 2 monitors, one will be the primary. You can change the primary to the alternative monitor temporarily and everything should switch with it.

If you want more fine-grained control, you should investigate a tool such as AutoHotKey which would allow you to write or record a macro to do what you want.